# How to organize a hierarchy of work items in TFS?

Tags: tfs, project-planning, workitem, tfs-workitem

For instance, say, I add a new work item named "Develope event aggregator".
I start to implement this feature and suddenly undestand that it contains more concrete tasks such as "Implement filtering by time", "Implement filtering by app name" and so on.

I need to orginize them so that there is should be a head of work items ("Develope event aggregator") and subordinated work items ("Implement filtering by time" and so on).

How to accomplish the task I descibed?

Comment: Which version of TFS? As of TFS2010, you cn create links between work items.

Comment: TFS2010. So you mean that I should in that case link subordinated items to the head item, am I right?

Comment: Details depend on the specific process template you're using (which one, agile?) but you can use Parent/Child for that. You can use that to break requirements down into finer-grained ones, and same for tasks into sub-tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a parent child link between these work items to get a hierarchy ie tree list of items.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293534.aspx

Comment: The link above is no longer working. This looks promising: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293534.aspx

Comment: Thanks @PaulF. Fixed the link